# Why is this regex selecting this text

Tags: regex

I am using the regex

```
(.*)\d.txt
```

on the expression

```
MyFile23.txt
```

Now the online tester says that using the above regex the mentioned string would be allowed (selected). My understanding is that it should not be allowed because there are two numeric digits 2 and 3 while the above regex expression has only one numeric digit in it i.e `\d`.It should have been `\d+`. My current expression reads. Zero of more of any character followed by one numeric digit followed by .txt. My question is why is the above string passing the regex expression ?

Comment: `.` will match also the digit character.

Comment: Also - you should escape last dot...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex `(.*)\d.txt` will still match `MyFile23.txt` because of `.*` which will match 0 or more of any character (including a digit).

So for the given input: `MyFile23.txt` here is the breakup:

```
.*   # matches MyFile2
\d   # matched 3
.    # matches a dot (though it can match anything here due to unescaped dot)
txt  # will match literal txt
```

To make sure it only matches `MyFile2.txt` you can use:

```
^\D*\d\.txt$
```

Where `^` and `$` are anchors to match start and end. `\D*` will match 0 or more non-digit.

Comment: but I am putting a numeric value after it. How do I fix my current expression ?

Comment: And to match `MyFile23.txt` you will need  `^\D*\d+\.txt$`

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you have has one group (.*) which would match using your example:`MyFile2`

because the . allows any character.
Furthermore the . in the pattern after this group is not escaped which will result in allowing another character of any kind.

To avoid this use:

```
(\D*)\d+\.txt
```

the group (\D*) would now match all non digit characters.

Comment: But you haven't *explained* why it's happening. The question asks "**Why** ... "

Comment: (\D*)\d+.text doesnt match myfile23.txt

Comment: @Rajeshwar it would ... but you have a group on the non digit part that is captured

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ the other answers allready mention the why... i thought i'd add how to get around this

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger Although I agree with you, a good answer should be complete. In this scenario, a good answer would be one that explains what's happening, and offer an alternative regex (like you've done)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the explanation, your "MyFile23.txt" matches the regex pattern:

[image]

A literal period `.` should always be escaped as `\.` else it will match "any character".

And finally, `(.*)` matches all the string from the beginning to the last digit (`MyFile2`). Have a look at the "MATCH INFORMATION" area on the right [at this page](https://regex101.com/r/qP0vR4/1).

So, I'd suggest the **following fix**:

`^\D*\d\.txt$` = beginning of a line/string, non-digit character, any number of repetitions, a digit, a literal period, a literal `txt`, and the end of the string/line (depending on the `m` switch, which depends on the input string, whether you have a list of words on separate lines, or just a separate file name).
Here is a [working example](https://regex101.com/r/qP0vR4/2).